# Seeing buffering everytime self.webview.open is used to open URL in quickly

Tags: python, quickly

I am new to developing apps with python-quickly. Here is the sample code i am trying.
Everytime I run this a video is played based on login.php. But it takes time to start or what I understand is that buffering takes place. Is there a way that the URL buffers only the first time and then the URL plays without buffering everytime after that?

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('smallbrowser')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('smallbrowser')

from smallbrowser_lib import Window
from smallbrowser.AboutSmallbrowserDialog import AboutSmallbrowserDialog
from smallbrowser.PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog import PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog

# See smallbrowser_lib.Window.py for more details about how this class works
class SmallbrowserWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "SmallbrowserWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
        """Set up the main window"""
        super(SmallbrowserWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutSmallbrowserDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesSmallbrowserDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.

        self.refreshbutton = self.builder.get_object("refreshbutton")
        self.urlentry = self.builder.get_object("urlentry")
        self.scrollwindow = self.builder.get_object("scrollwindow")
        self.webview =  WebKit.WebView()  
        self.scrollwindow.add(self.webview)
        self.webview.show()
        self.webview.open("login.php")  

    def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self, widget):
        print "refresh"
```